# Один обработчик для всех picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

На форме есть 14 picturebox`ов, для всех один и тот же метод при нажатии

```
OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
openFile.Filter = "Файлы изображений (*.bmp, *.jpg, *.png, *mpeg, *tif, *tiff)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png;*mpeg;*tif;*tiff";
openFile.ShowDialog();
FileName = openFile.FileName; 
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = FileName;
```

Упирается все в последнюю строчку, где задается путь к файлу. Можно ли как-то сделать один метод для всех в этом случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался

```
public void openPicture(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFile.Filter = "Файлы изображений (*.bmp, *.jpg, *.png, *mpeg, *tif, *tiff)|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.png;*mpeg;*tif;*tiff";
            openFile.ShowDialog();
            Path = openFile.FileName; 
            PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
            pb.ImageLocation = Path;
        }
```

Comment: Идея использовать sender

Answer (score 2):

обработайте object sender в зависимости который элемент, и вы получите желаемый результат.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)  
{  
   MessageBox((Button)sender.Text);
}
```

Comment: Можно подробнее, пожалуйста? То, что Вы прислали, не работает